# T-SQL The conflict occurred in database when delete a record from a parent table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, cascade

I have a trigger which deletes `Attendants` when an `Employee` is deleted. However I get this error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Attendants_Employee". The conflict occurred in database "MYTESTWORKS", table "dbo.Attendants", column 'EmployeeId'.

[image: Click to see the relationship diagram.]

I cannot define `ON DELETE CASCADE` between `Attendants` and `Employee` because it causes relation cycle error. That's because I defined a trigger to do the job but it seems not to work properly.

I need to catch the delete process before it is executed, so I can delete Attendants.

`Employee` table has another relationship with another table defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE` so I cannot implement an `INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGER`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Drop that FK and control relations manually. You are already halfway there.

Comment: why mssql disable me from removing it? are these relationships wrong ?

Comment: You cannot write a trigger that can "fix things" for a constraint - the constraints are checked earlier before the modification is *allowed* to proceed, before the trigger gets a chance to fire.

Comment: Sounds like something in the design is not quite right. Perhaps you could post the ddl for the tables?

Comment: Just from personal experience, I'd like suggest that you might want to take this opportunity to decide that you never want to delete rows from your employee table (unless that row is literally a mistake and never should have been there).  Instead, add a termination date, and a 'logical delete' flag so that old records can be properly ignored.  But I can almost guarantee that there's a point where you will wish that your Employee table contained information about employees that were in the company even though they no longer are.  Food for thought, I know it doesn't speak to your question.